# Minimum values excluding 0 (data frame rows)

Tags: r, dataframe, row, minimum

```
datas[1:n_row, ]    
                       IBOV     ABEV3 AEDU3 ALLL3
1       2000-01-03 1.0120990 0.0000000     0     0
2       2000-01-04 0.9860183 0.1463091     0     0
3       2000-01-05 0.9565528 0.1876168     0     0
4       2000-01-06 0.9286969 0.2059637     0     0
5       2000-01-07 0.9163109 0.1996892     0     0
6       2000-01-10 0.8943083 0.2147309     0     0
```

I m using :

```
MIN = apply(EWMA_SD252[,2:102],1,min)
```

to create another matrix of row minimuns, but i want to get the MIN values excluding 0 (values are always positive)
any ideias ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple logical extraction for `x>0`:

```
MIN = apply(EWMA_SD252[,2:102], 1, function(x) min(x[x>0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace 0 values with max value , then keep the same code to get min by row.

```
mat[mat==0] <- max(mat)
apply(mat,1,min)
```